# Getting a pyserial error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'byte' and 'int'

Tags: python, pyserial, python-3.7

I'm trying to read a serial output from a device and getting the above error.

Added int() in the following line and get same error:
rtn = self.ser.read(int(self.numbytes))

```
def doSerial(self, cmd=''):
    self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port,self.baud)
    time.sleep(1)
    if self.ser.isOpen():
        if self.sel == 5:#RSOIS
            self.StatusButton.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"))
            self.statusLabel.setText('connected')
            time.sleep(2)
            while True:
                self.numbytes = self.ser.inWaiting()#size of input buffer
                print ('bytes in waiting: '+str(self.numbytes))
                rtn = self.ser.read(int(self.numbytes))
                if self.numbytes > 0:
                    self.Response_textEdit.setText(self.ser.read(rtn))
                else:
                    self.Response_textEdit.setText('No serial ouput/n')
                    break
    else:
        print ('serial not open')
```

I get 'bytes in waiting: 74' from my print statement, any ideas?

Here is the actual error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SensComm\SensComRes.py", line 95, in doSerial
  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 268, in read
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'bytes' and 'int'

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace please?

Comment: [inWaiting()](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.inWaiting) has been deprecated.

Comment: Try printing `self.numbytes` right after it's been set. Add `print(repr(self.numbytes))` and check if it's what you expected. (Share it with us if  you still need help.)

Comment: Also try `self.ser.in_waiting` (no parentheses) instead of `inwaiting`, presuming you're running pyserial 3.0 or later. You could also punt and just use `if self.numbytes` instead of comparing it to 0, or just use the length of rtn. But it would be easier to answer this with the full stack trace. You imply the error is on the `rtn = ... ` line but there is no `>` operator on that line, so it might well be somewhere inside pyserial but we can't tell without the stack trace..

Comment: Maybe I should use readline(s) instead?

Comment: @Steve added full stack trace

Comment: @Deepstop added full stack trace and tried self.ser.in_waiting, same result

Comment: Just randomly, can you try to do `self.numbytes.decode()`? It looks like that's what the error is speaking about, maybe `self.numbytes` was loaded as bytes and not converted to `int`

Comment: @Nakor wouldn't using int(self.numbytes) like I have in my code convert it to an integer?

Comment: @djeffk58 You actually can't use int on a bytes data type, it raises `ValueError`. From the traceback the error is in PySerial but at line 268 it's a simple comparison to zero `size > 0` which is being passed directly from your program (presuming you are running pyserial 3.3 which is the package I'm looking at. You can satisfy yourself of the data type with `print(type(self.numbytes))` just before the line which causes the error. If `self.numbytes` really was a bytes object your print statement would look like `bytes in waiting: b'\x1b\x00'`.

Comment: @Deepstop The same error occurs if I use the int() or not. I just added it to see if it would correct the problem

Comment: @djeffk58 yes. See my answer to your question below. I believe the error is occurring 2 lines down in your program, as I would expect you to see that error given the way that statement is written. I think you want `setText(rtn)`, not `setText(self.serial.read(rtn))`

Comment: @Deepstop I believe your right, let me try.

Comment: You probably also want to put the read after the check for numbytes>0. If it is zero you don't want to read 0 bytes. In fact you could just put `setText(self.serial.read(self.numbytes))` after the if statement and remove `rtn = self.ser.read(int(self.numbytes))` entirely,

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the error isn't on this line `self.Response_textEdit.setText(self.ser.read(rtn))`? You are providing `serial.read` with `rtn` as its size parameter. The variable `rtn` is the output of the previous `serial.read`, and will be a bytes object and will raise the error you are getting.